# Facebook API error : (#210) Subject must be a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to delete an application tab from a facebook page.

According to the documentation, I should issue a DELETE request to "https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/tabs/app_ID" with a "manage_pages" access token, but when I do so I get the error "(#210) Subject must be a page."

I have requested the user for "manage_pages" permission and I have the correct access_token (GET Method works perfectly to show all the details).

The exact request is: 
https://graph.facebook.com/270936169730418/tabs/app_533644953422033 (with an access token)

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong??

P.S I am using JS SDK and also trying to do this in the graph api explorer but results are the same.

Comment: I would file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with the access token. When using the Graph API Explorer (and checking "manage_pages") you might think that the access token showing at the top is a page access token. It is not.

You need to do GET /me/accounts
Then find the page you want and there is an access_token. Copy this and paste it into the Access Token input field at the top. Now do the DELETE [PAGE_ID]/apps_[APP_ID] and it will work.

Comment: Big thanks, it worked like charm. So happy that you saved my day :) Thank you once again!

Comment: Great Answer, I'm working with Facebook Live videos `POST /{page_id}/live_videos`   and is the same, to make it work I need to send the Token related to page_id returned on `GET /me/accounts` and not the token returned on login.

Comment: How does this work with an app secret?  I changed my access token to what you suggested but it doesn't work now because the app secret is not correct (makes sense, I just changed the token).  How would I get an app secret to match?

Comment: @DavidRhoderick The app secret doesn't change when you change access token. It's always the same. Am I misunderstanding?